How does this overcurrent circuit work?
Could someone explain how this short-circuit protection circuit works?
As I understand it, Q4 and Q3 form an equivalent circuit of a thyristor, and it functions as a switch. When the thyristor triggers, +12V is applied to the gate of the field-effect transistor, and it turns off. Is that correct?
I'm particularly interested in the right part of the circuit, after the FET. What is the purpose of C1? Does this capacitor create a delay for the protection to activate?
In general, I would like to know more about how the right part of the circuit works.


Your assessment of how the circuit works is correct.  In summary: under normal operation conditions, M2 is kept turned on by R9.  When the load current is too high, Q5 turns on, which triggers an SCR formed by Q3 & Q4, which forces M2 off.  The SCR remains on (thus keeping M2 off) until the +12V power is turned off.

What is the purpose of C1? Does this capacitor create a delay for the protection to activate?

Short answer: yes, C1 causes a delay.  The time constant is set by C1 (100n) & R8 (1kΩ), so is about 0.1ms.

In general, I would like to know more about how the right part of the circuit works.

This part of the circuit simply biases the voltage at the base of Q5 to adjust the level at which Q5 triggers the SCR.  Q6 is wired as a forward-biased diode (its base is connected to its collector).  R13 (10kΩ) sets the current in this diode at about 1mA.  R14 (3kΩ) allows a fraction of this voltage to bias the voltage at Q5 base terminal.  With no current flowing in R6, Q5-base voltage is set by the Q6 Vbe and the voltage divider formed by R14 (3kΩ) & R8 (1kΩ).  The values in the circuit mean that the bias voltage will be one-quarter of the Vbe of Q6.
Assuming Q5 will trigger the SCR when its Vbe reaches 0.6V, then the voltage across R5 required to trigger Q5 will be:
0.6V - (0.6V/4) = 3/4 x 0.6V = 0.45V.
The current in R6 required to reach this voltage is: 0.45 / 0.1Ω = 4.5A.
As others have pointed out, the current at which this circuit will trip is dependent upon the characteristics of Q5 and Q6; in particular Vbe, which is very temperature-dependent.  As temperature increases, Vbe drops, so as temperature increases the current that will trip the circuit reduces.

Yes, there is a time constant due to C1 of about 75usec. Higher overcurrents will trip faster.
Q6 is an attempt to bias the sense transistor Q5 close to conduction so the circuit does not require the entire 600mV or so across the 0.1Ω sense resistor.
I'm not sure how well that works in terms of predictable trip point and temperature sensitivity. It's relatively crude compared to something like a differential pair.
Q3 and Q4 and the MOSFET M2 work as you suggest. The threshold voltage of M2 has to be high enough that it mostly turns off with 800mV or so on the gate.
The circuit may be prone to false triggering if the rate of rise dv/dt of V2 is high enough.

C1 reduces the sensitivity to small (short) current spikes drawn by load. Otherwise (without C1) every small current rise would cause thyristor to latch up and turns off the mosfet.

Fixing ideas, here is the behavior between 0°C, 27°C and 50°C when powering on.
Changing the load, power ON, i(load) vs time.
Made with microcap v12

